# ViewResult.ViewName property empty in unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my unit test, the ViewResult.ViewName property is always empty when i use the action name for the view:

```
return View(model);
or
return View();
```

Is that by design?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is by design:

```
protected internal ViewResult View()
{
    return this.View(null, null, null);
}
```

Checkout [MVCContrib.TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) for better syntax:

```
// act
var actual = controller.Index();

// assert
actual.AssertViewRendered();
```

Comment: Do you know where does it get my viewname from?

Comment: From the name of the action that is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is indeed:

```
protected internal ViewResult View()
{
    return this.View(null, null, null);
}

protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, 
    string masterName, object model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        base.ViewData.Model = model;
    }
    ViewResult result = new ViewResult();
    result.ViewName = viewName;
    result.MasterName = masterName;
    result.ViewData = base.ViewData;
    result.TempData = base.TempData;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Huh? then where does it get my viewname from?