# MVC 3 - Unit Test Controller Result

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

I am writing unit tests to test MVC 3 controllers.  I want to ensure that that the view that comes back from the controller is the right view.  In my unit test I have:

```
[Test]
            public void It_Should_Return_The_Right_Page()
            {
                FormController fc = this.CreateFormController();
                var view = fc.FindX();
                Assert.AreEqual("FindX", view.ViewName);
            }
```

In my controller, I have:

```
public ViewResult FindX()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

This fails because ViewName is null.  If I change the call to say `return View("FindX")` and explicitly define the view to be returned, it works.  However, I would like to avoid this if possible.  Is there a generally accepted way to approach this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ViewResult.ViewName property empty in unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912463/viewresult-viewname-property-empty-in-unit-test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't set a viewname, then isn't ViewName being null the correct and expected outcome, so code your test accordingly.

```
Assert.IsNull(view.ViewName);
```

Comment: @Xhalent - It would be, but I want to make a test that says "The action that was returned is the right one.", so I need to tie to something specifically to that action.  It looks like ViewBag.Title is a reasonable choice after looking into it, since that will have the right title for the page.

Comment: Then set the viewname in the controller. You don't have to leave it blank. That's what I do as a matter of course, even if the view matches the action name.

Comment: @Xhalent - sorry - I think I didn't explain myself well enough.  I am aware that I can set the name in the controller, but it felt  a little weird to have an explicit string literal in there, as the default with no parameter would go to the correct View anyway.  I was wondering if there was a better method.

Comment: @skaz. Good point, I wouldn't recommend the testing of assigned literals either. I set the action strings as constants in the controller class and then compare against those constants. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @Xhalent - Can you elaborate in more detail?  Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really the right answer, but the comments illuminate the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you want to convey is: Assert that the default view for this method was returned.  One way to convey this is using this line:

```
var view = fc.FindX();

Assert.IsNull(view.ViewName)
```

But this doesn't convey your intent very well.  One way to convey it more clearly is to create an extension method on ActionResult or ViewResult called AssertIsDefaultView like so:

```
public static class ActionResultAssertions
{
    public static void AssertIsDefaultView(this ActionResult actionResult)
    {
        var viewResult = actionResult as ViewResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
        Assert.IsNull(viewResult.ViewName);
    }
}
```

Then in your test you can say:

```
var view = fc.FindX();
view.AssertIsDefaultView();
```

[MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) has a set of these assertions (I think the name of the method is AssertViewRendered), but I prefer to just write the extensions myself so I can understand MVC better.

Comment: The line 'Assert.IsNull(viewResult.ViewName);' should read 'Assert.IsTrue(string.IsEmpty(viewResult.ViewName))'. In my case this property is never null but empty. Apart from that I like this response as it shows a way how to better express the intention of the test.

Comment: or even Assert.IsNullOrEmpty(viewResult.ViewName);

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me

```
public ViewResult FindX()
    {
        return View("FindX");
    }
```