# How to assert for action return type in xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, xunit.net

my try block

```
 try
        {
            ServiceModel task = service.Get(id);
            service.Delete(0);
            service.saveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

my catch block

```
catch(Exception ex)
                {
                string msg = ex.Message;
                    return View();
                }
```

I tried like below

```
 var TaskPortalController = this.CreateTasksController();
            int id = 123;
            // Act
          var result = TaskPortalController.Delete(id) as ViewResult;
            // Assert
            Assert.Equal("Delete", result.ViewName);
```

Getting null value in `result.ViewName` where i am expecting "Delete".

so How to assert for action return type

```
enter code here
```

Comment: `result` is null, or `result.ViewName` is null? What is the return type of your Delete method _from the method signature_, and what is the actual return type you return from the method's implementation?

Comment: in "ActionResult" im getting null, "ActionResult" is the return type of my Delete method.

Comment: Actually in try I was returning Delete View and in catch returning Error view so need to differ which view name is returning ?

Comment: It looks like you are asking about `ViewResult`, not `Action`. `ViewResult` is a return type used for MVC endpoints; `Action` is a delegate type that represents a function and does not have a `ViewName` property.

What are you actually trying to prove with your test? Are you testing that it did not error and its returning a result that confirms deletion happened?

Comment: [I'm not able to reproduce your issue with your posted code and filling in the gaps with assumptions](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MEC2OD). Please post a [mre].

Comment: In try block I am returning  delete view and in Catch block returning Error view. So need to check which view is coming in Assert

Comment: See [ViewResult.ViewName property empty in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912463/viewresult-viewname-property-empty-in-unit-test)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with

```
Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
```

if redirected to another action,the result will be
RedirectToActionResult
[image]